# High Voltage and Low Charge - Analogy (ESD & Lightning)

Tags: voltage, capacitance, esd, lightning

How can something have high voltage but low charge?

Can anyone provide an analogy for this?

I was going through the ESD topics and read the ESD events usually have high voltage but have low charge?

I am actually confused with the ESD event principle/concept. Like, If something has high voltage, does it mean that it has a lot of charges having similar or equal electrical Electrical potential values or does it mean that it has less number of charges, charged to high potential.

This is where I am not able to understand.

Q=CV. Without talking about capacitance or talking less about capacitance, can someone provide an analogy of High voltage and Low charge?

And do Lightnings that occur, also have high voltage and low charge? If Lightning is also an ESD event, how come Lightnings are very dangerous but small ESD events are not that dangerous for Normal person?

Comment: Why shouldn't something have high voltage but low charge? I don't understand where you see a contradiction. Voltage is defined as "energy per charge", nothing more, nothing less. Your question does nothing to explain where you see that problem?

Comment: I am actually confused with the ESD event principle/concept. Like, If something has high voltage, does it mean that it has a lot of charges having similar or equal electrical Electrical potential values or does it mean that it has less number of charges, charged to high potential. I don't know whether my previous sentence makes sense. Would be glad if you could break up the definitions of voltage and charge in simple terms and provide an analogy with respect to ESD/Lightning events.

Comment: Momentum = mass x velocity. If you asked me to explain that without reference to mass, would that be sensible? It's a direct analogy to Q = CV because, as Marcus mentioned voltage can be seen as \$\dfrac{dW}{dq}\$ just as velocity is \$\dfrac{dW}{dp}\$ where p is momentum and W is energy and q is charge.

Comment: Ok. Could you please explain by considering the capacitance parameter? I am trying to understand intuitively about something having high voltage but low charge. An analogy with working might help me a lot.

Comment: Do you know the energy formula for a capacitor, \$W = \frac{1}{2}\cdot CV^2\$. It is derived from Q = CV and loses Q along the way. Just as the mechanical energy of a moving mass is \$W = \frac{1}{2}\cdot mv^2\$ where m = mass and v = speed (velocity) and loses momentum (p) along the way. I'm asking so that I can understand your understandings on the subject.

Comment: yeah, honestly, none of the analogies we can make (and momentum is the best I can come up with, too) are going to be mathematically easier than the trivial \$Q=CV\$. How much easier could we possibly make it?

Comment: Like charges repel, so work must be done to bring them together. This work done gets  stored as potential energy of the system. Suppose you're charged to +Q and touch an IC pin, then the potential energy that went in charging your body converts to kinetic energy(current) and may destroy the IC.

Comment: Not posted as an answer but an analogy that might make some sense.  You are at a bonfire its temperature is several hundred degrees.  If you fell into it you would be badly burnt (possibly die) but a tiny spark is blown by the wind and touches your skin.  The energy is tiny so while you feel it you are not injured.  The spark relies on its thermal mass to pass on energy.  Similarly if capacitance is tiny the voltage can discharge quickly and safely: charge \$ Q = C \cdot V \$ and energy \$ \frac{C \cdot V^2}{2}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does a container containing high pressure air need to contain a lot of air? Answer: It doesn't. The container can be tiny. Pressure is determined by how much force is being exerted per molecule of air, not how much air there is. Sure with more pressure you can force more air into the same space, but the container can always be smaller so high pressure isn't synonymous with having a lot of air.

In this case, pressure is the voltage and amount (mass) of air is the current.

---

Why is lightning dangerous but ESD not? Remember, it is current that kills, not voltage. However, you need enough voltage to push that enough current through you for it to be lethal. That means there has to be enough power so that the high currents current can be maintained while the voltage is pushing hard.

Lightning has a lot more power behind it than ESD. When ESD is forcing its way through you it's petering out so the currents that flow are limited. This is not the case with lightning where there is enough power behind it that large currents will continue to flow even as the lightning is pushing very hard to get through you.

It's similar to how a tiny piece of sand being thrown at you is a lot less dangerous than a giant rock being thrown at you at the same speed. One has a lot more energy behind it and will not slow down very much when it hits you.

Comment: nice answer, especially the second part!

Comment: Thank you for the analogy and the answer. I am getting some good clarity from your answer after some good contemplation. But I don't get this line "When ESD is forcing its way through you it's petering out so the currents that flow are limited" . Could you please edit your answer to explain why this force need to reduce in the case of ESD and hence the current is limited?

Comment: @Newbie The power something has is limited. Power is Voltage * Current just like power is Torque * RPM. If you need to use a lot of voltage to push through something you are going to end up with less current since your power is limited.

Comment: OK. Got it. Final question, how does one identify that if an Event (Like ESD or Lightning) has High Power or Low Power?

Comment: @Newbie You can't rigorously identify it as such high and low are relative terms. You use numbers if you really need to know. Low for you would be extremely high and lethal for a semiconductor device.

Answer (score 2):

> Like, If something has high voltage, does it mean that it has a lot of charges

No, it means that a unit of charge holds a lot of energy. That's the definition of voltage: energy per charge.

> does it mean that it has less number of charges, charged to high potential.

It doesn't say **anything** about the amount of charge (charge isn't really countable, but you just mean "much charge").

Charge and voltage are only linked in certain physical objects (like capacitors), and then through the simple formula Q=CV you give in your question. There's really nothing more to it; you can't generally say "an object with high voltage always has low charge" or "… always has high charge" or anything.